# Setting a watcher for a data variable in different component in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, watch

I have two components: component `A` and component `B`. `A.vue` is like:

```
export default {
    name: 'A',
    data () {
        var: true
    }
}
```

`B.vue` is:

```
import A from './A'
export default {
    name: 'B',
    components: {
        A
    }
}
```

I want to use the dynamic value of variable `var` of component `A` in component `B`. I set a watcher therefore:

```
import A from './A'
export default {
    name: 'B',
    watch: {
        A.data().var: func () {
            console.log('Value of var changed in A.')
        }
    }
    components: {
        A
    }
}
```

However, this approach does not work. Components `A` and `B` does not have the child-parent relationship, and therefore, I cannot use props. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that both *instances of* `A` and `B` live within the same root instance, you could use that root as an event hub for the communication between the 2 components.

**Step 1 |** The the root template that calls `handleAVarChange` when needed:

```
const rootTemplate = `
```

```
    <div class="root">
        <A @var-change="handleAVarChange"></A>
        <B v-bind:AVar="AVar"></B>
    </div>
```

```
`;
```

**Step 2 |** the Vue root script that implements `rootTemplate`:

```
const root = new Vue({
    template: rootTemplate,
    data() {
        return { AVar: null };
    },
    methods: {

        handleAVarChange(value) {
            this.AVar = value;
        }
    }
});
```

- **`template`**: The template that both includes `A` and `B`
- **`data`** returns an object with property `AVar`, which we'll use to store the source variable on `A`.
- **`methods.handleAVarChange`** is available as event handler within `root.template`.

**Step 3 |** `$emit` an event named `'var-change'` with the new value from `A`:

```
export default {
    name: 'A',
    data () {
        return {
            Var: true,
        }
    },

    methods: {
        onSomeEvent(varValue) {
            this.$emit('var-change', varValue);
            // or maybe...
            this.$emit('var-change', this.Var);
        },
    },
}
```

**Step 4 |** Make sure that `AVar` is set as `prop` within `B`:

```
export default {
    name: 'B',
    props: ['AVar'],
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I had resorted exactly to this approach after posting this question.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using a simple [state management (Vue docs)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch) for your problem.

```
var store = {
  debug: false,
  state: {
      myVar: false
  },
  setMyVarAction (value) {
    this.state.myVar = value
  }
}
```

And assign the store to your components `A` and `B`:

```
data () {
  return  {
    sharedStore: store.state
  }
}
```

[jsfriddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n1eb4h8k/) with a working example.